# SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, migrations

Tenho um projeto onde fiz algumas migrations, porem quando fiz consegui rodar as migrations tranquilamente. Recentemente formatei meu computador, instalei o PostgresSQL e fiz o meu "restore" do meu DB. Nisso baixei meu projeto novamente e assim que fui dar `php artisan migrate` apareceu o seguinte erro.

```
    In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "qusuario.tu_permissao" does not exist  
  LINE 1: select * from "qusuario"."tu_permissao"                                              
                        ^ (SQL: select * from "qusuario"."tu_permissao")                       


In Connection.php line 330:

  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "qusuario.tu_permissao" does not exist  
  LINE 1: select * from "qusuario"."tu_permissao"
```

Nisso tentei mudar as ordens da migrations, tentei criar a table "tu_permissao" como diz no erro, porem quando criei e rodei o `php artisan migrate` ele me retornou que a table ja existe.

Minha `migrate`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTuPermissaosTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('qusuario.tu_permissao', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('mid');
            $table->string('nome', 60);
            $table->string('mdesc', 120);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('qusuario.tu_permissao');
    }
}
```

Ordem das `migrations`:

[image: migrations ordem]

Comment: Por que está sendo executado um `SELECT` no banco quando se é executado o `migrate`?

Comment: @Woss, não sei ao certo, suponho que faça parte do `migrate`, mas esse erro ocorre assim que faço o `php artisan migrate`

Comment: `qusuario` é o nome dê que? Do banco? Até aonde sei isso se configura no `.env` ou `config/database.php` e não no proprio migration, se a intenção é usar ponto como prefixo, acho que já esta errado, ou no minimo atrapalhando o migration, já que o ponto é usado para coisas especificas nas querys. Se o ponto é só prefixo mesmo troque todos por `_` em todos lugares que se referem ao nome da tabela

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o banco já esta configurado, minha duvida é por que não consigo realizar o `migrate`

Comment: Banco é uma coisa, tabela é outra, se o migration gera as tabelas então estar configurado não faz sentido, a não ser que você não saiba a diferença, se já existe as tabelas no banco e as fez manualmente nem tem sentido usar o migration. De resto se atente ao que eu já falei e estou tornando a repetir, o `.` ali no `Schema::create('qusuario.tu_permissao'` não aparenta fazer sentido, a não ser que você esteja querendo forçar criar uma tabela em um banco especifico, se for o caso então esta configurando errado e provavelmente (não posso afirmar) esta atrapalhando a lógica do migration.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento meu banco de dados foi configurado com varios Schemas, por isso o `Schema::create('qusuario.tu_permissao')`

Comment: Mas os `migrates` antes da `tu_permissao` funciona normalmente, por isso não tenho ideia do que seja.

Comment: Como eu já disse, estou quase certo que você imagina que funcione com ponto para separar, mas não funciona. Até aonde sei, mas posso estar enganado. Ao menos talvez não seja esperado pelo laravel/eloquent

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O Sistema esta online a 11 anos, acho que faz um tempinho que funciona com o `.`, mas como eu disse minha duvida não é se meu banco esta configurado corretamente, por que já fiz varias `migrations`, porem **essa** aconteceu esse especifico erro

Comment: E esta executando algum seed? Porque se o select é gerado pelo migration ou seed ele esta esperando algo errado e ainda por cima em um momento ele separa `"foo"."bar"` e no outro ele junta ``"foo.bar"``, como se fosse só o nome da tabela usando aspas.

Comment: O mais estranho é você afirmar que o sistema esta online a 11 anos, sendo que o Laravel só tem 8 anos, ou seja, então antes foi feito de uma forma e com certeza não foi com o migrations do Laravel

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pior que não, não executo nenhuma `seed`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento estou falando do banco, o sistema antes rodava com `CodeIgniter`, refiz a logica com base no `Laravel` e dai em diante esta funcionando normal. Minhas `migrations`, meus `seeders`, rodam normalmente, só essa em questão que deu esse erro especifico.

Comment: Não importa, fazer com migration e fazer sem migration (antes) são duas coisas diferentes, algo claramente foi configurado errado, eu não sei afirmar se é possivel setar o banco diretamente no Scheme::create, até aonde sei vc cria uma conexão pra cada banco e afirma isto antes do create para cada migration. A unica outra possibilidade, acaso o Laravel aceite setar o banco diretamente na string, seria se o seu usuário postgres não tiver permissão de criar tabelas no banco `qusuario`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento bom obrigado pela tentativa de ajuda, vou continuar meus testes aqui e qualquer resolução, eu retorno com a mesma no post. :)

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado aos que tentaram me ajudar. Resolvi o meu problema da seguinte maneira:
Havia um `Provider` que dependia da minha `table`, **`tu_permissao`**, nisso toda vez que eu tentava rodar um comando como `php artisan migrate`, meu `Provider` dava erro de tabela não encontrada, mas também não conseguia cria-la, por conta do erro em questão, notando isso, comentei minha `function` do `Provider` e rodei o `migrate` normalmente. Vou deixar abaixo a `function` que estava impedindo a criação da minha `table`.

```
public function boot()
    {
            foreach ($this->listPerm() as $prr) {
            Gate::df($prr->name, function ($us) use ($prr) {
                return $us->validar($prr->prf) || ($us->su() || $us->adm());
            });
        }
    }

    public function listPerm()
    {
        return TuPermissao::with('prf')->get();
    }
```